# How to add documentation to package (not to the package's functions)

Tags: r, devtools, r-package, roxygen2, r-usethis

I am trying to get documentation to show up for an actual package (not its functions, since that's done automatically when documentating the package) through the `help()` or `?` functions.

For example, using the following:

```
?dplyr
```

We get:

```
dplyr-package {dplyr}   R Documentation
dplyr: A Grammar of Data Manipulation
Description
To learn more about dplyr, start with the vignettes: browseVignettes(package = "dplyr")

Author(s)
Maintainer: Hadley Wickham hadley@rstudio.com (ORCID)

Authors:

Romain François (ORCID)

Lionel Henry

Kirill Müller (ORCID)

Other contributors:

RStudio [copyright holder, funder]

See Also
Useful links:

https://dplyr.tidyverse.org

https://github.com/tidyverse/dplyr

Report bugs at https://github.com/tidyverse/dplyr/issues

[Package dplyr version 1.0.7 Index]
```

I created a basic package, `cats`, through Hillary Parker's tutorial: https://hilaryparker.com/2014/04/29/writing-an-r-package-from-scratch/. I installed it and confirmed that it works correctly, e.g., getting help docs for the one function:

```
?cat_function
```

Gives:

```
cat_function {cats} R Documentation
A Cat Function
Description
This function allows you to express your love of cats.

Usage
cat_function(love = TRUE)
Arguments
love    
Do you love cats? Defaults to TRUE.

Examples
cat_function()
[Package cats version 0.0.0.9000 Index]
```

However, trying to get docs for the package itself:

```
?cats
No documentation for ‘cats’ in specified packages and libraries:
you could try ‘??cats’
```

From the function help, I can click on `Index`, and then I get an OK "help" page, and I can also from there click on `DESCRIPTION file`, but these are definitely not like what `help(cats)` would output.

How can I get the same `help()` call for my `cats` package? I think I must have read all tutorials about creating a package but only saw something about adding vignettes which seem to be a different thing (though I did try adding a vignette, and the help docs still didn't come up). I also tried adding a readme file, but alas, same result. What's the trick? =)

Edit: Actually been using `usethis` through `devtools` to install and `document()` but I don't think this would make a difference as I didn't see this particular form of package documentation documented on any of the tutorials.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're using `usethis`, you can do `usethis::use_package_doc()`. See docs [here](https://usethis.r-lib.org/reference/use_package_doc.html).

You could also read [Hadley's book on R packages](https://r-pkgs.org/man.html#man-packages) which explains what this is doing.

Comment: Omg, amazing! Just exactly what I was looking for! Tested it and it works beautifully! I spent a lot of time on that book and that particular page. But searching (Ctr+F) for "use_package_doc" doesn't provide any results. Could you please point me out where he describes this?

Comment: I would have also thought that `create()` would take care of this for you as well! It seems a pretty logical step to setup along with all the rest IMHO. Thanks again for sharing the solution.

Comment: You are right - he doesn't specify the name of the function. I'm not sure why that is. He does outlay the process for doing it manually though in section 10.6 (basically, create a 'packagename.R' file and document a `NULL` object).